# Powershell get-aduser not showing all results

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to pull some data from AD but am getting some confusing results. I'm running:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | select userPrincipalName, msTSLSProperty01
```

and it presents me with all users, 6 of which have something in the msTSLSProperty01 field. The confusing thing is that it should return 42 users with something in that field. Any reason it shows blank for users who have data in that field?

Edit 1: In addition, when I run:

```
Get-ADUser username -Properties msTSLSProperty01 | select msTSLSProperty01
```

it returns and empty set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple DCs in your environment, you may just be seeing replication delays if the changes you are expecting were only recently written to those user attributes. Powershell might be querying a different DC than whatever other tool you're using to verify those attributes exist.  You can explicitly tell PowerShell to talk to a specific DC with the `-Server` argument in the `Get-ADUser` command.

Alternatively, you might have permissions issues preventing you from reading that attribute for a subset of your users.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, these changes have been live for many months. I tried specifying the server as

    Get-ADUser username -Server server1.domain.net -Properties msTSLSProperty01 | select msTSLSProperty01

and it still returns an empty subset. I'm also running as a domain administrator

Comment: Based on your comment about permissions issues, Ryan, I ran powershell "as an administrator" and it successfully pulled all of the data that it was supposed to. Thanks for your comment on that!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. UAC catches everyone now and then. It's odd though. Default permissions on most containers in AD grant read access to anyone in Domain Users, so you shouldn't need to be DA normally.  Were the users you couldn't read properly in a container (or sub container) that had disabled permissions inheritance?

Comment: I don't believe there are any permissions inheritance issues but I did notice that 5 of the 6 users that were returned were all Domain Admins in the same OU as myself.

Comment: The DA's have different permissions than others because of the AdminSDHolder process. There are additional groups affected by this as well. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/05/07/five-common-questions-about-adminsdholder-and-sdprop/

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to @RyanBolger's [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/825719/137255), this PowerShell script will query each DC (or will report the error if they don't have the ADWS service installed).  That may be enough for you to determine which server's missing those users; or at least to see which servers aren't (i.e. limiting the possible candidates to those without ADWS / those which error when queried through PS).

```
clear-host
Get-AdDomainController -Filter * | %{
    $count = 0
    $myError = ''
    try {
        $count = (Get-AdUser -Filter * -server $_.Name).Count
    } catch {
        $myError = $_.ToString()
    }
    (New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $_.Name
        Site = $_.Site
        OS = $_.OperatingSystem 
        Count = $count
        Error = $myError
     })
} | select Name, Count, Site, OS, Error | sort Count, Error, Name | format-table -autosize
```